# Exception Unparseable date

Tags: java, android

```
 SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    String dtc = "2014-03-27T11:31:42.798Z";

            Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = readDate.parse(dtc);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.d("myLog", "dateExcep " + e);
                }
```

try{} catch{} have exception: 03-27 16:29:48.459: D/myLog(19388): dateExcep java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-03-27T11:31:42.798Z" (at offset 23)

Answer (score 4):

The `Z` in your format pattern is the problem. That represents an RFC 822 time zone, which can't just be `Z`. If your input will *always* be in UTC, you can use:

```
// The Z is now quoted as a literal.
SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
readDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```

Note that it's important to set the time zone here, as otherwise it will assume the value is in your current system time zone.

In ["normal" Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you could use `X` instead to represent an ISO-8601 time zone offset specifier, but that isn't supported in the [Android `SimpleDateTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) right now.

Answer (score 3):

Try `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");`

instead of

`SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

Where Z is the TimeZone.

Answer (score 2):

Offset 23 relates to the `Z` at the end of your date string. `Z` is intended to designate a time zone as by the [RFC822Timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) . Check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for references on time zones.